# Angular - REST Service XML Links with $Resource

Tags: angularjs, rest, silverstripe

I am using Angular with SilverStripe for my backend. I am using this module https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-restfulserver for my REST API instead of building it myself.

When the API returns a list with a many_many relationship it looks like

```
<Recipe href="http://localhost/groceryList/api/v1/Recipe/2.xml">
<Title>Chilli</Title>
<ID>2</ID>
<Ingredients linktype="many_many" href="http://localhost/groceryList/api/v1/Recipe/2/Ingredients.xml">
    <Ingredient href="http://localhost/groceryList/api/v1/Ingredient/5.xml" id="5"/>
    <Ingredient href="http://localhost/groceryList/api/v1/Ingredient/6.xml" id="6"/>
    <Ingredient href="http://localhost/groceryList/api/v1/Ingredient/7.xml" id="7"/>
</Ingredients>
</Recipe>
```

My question is 2 part.

1. Why is the collection of ingredients a bunch of links? I was hoping it would contain the name of each ingredient. Is this how REST is suppose to work?
2. Using Angular $Resource, how can easily get the ingredients to loop through using ng-repeat?

Comment: I would recommend, to look at the following repos:
https://github.com/colymba/silverstripe-restfulapi
https://github.com/silverstripe-europe-meetup/silverstripe-todo

Comment: I'll check those out, thanks for the links. Hoping colymbas module will return the json in a more usable format.

Comment: Definitely try my module: https://github.com/colymba/silverstripe-restfulapi if you get issues using it, post something on GitHub...

Comment: @colymba, i tried your module out over the weekend. So far it seems like a much better solution for what I am trying to do. If I run into issues or anything i'll be sure to post on github, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to convert your XML to JSON with https://code.google.com/p/x2js/ or https://github.com/johngeorgewright/angular-xml, so you need an HttpInterceptor to convert all your requests and responses from the server.

I don't know why you don't have the name of each ingredient into your response, I think you need to change the response returned by your API, but I don't know how SilverStripe work.

Comment: I can pretty easily convert the response to json, so that won't be an issue. 

Changing the response may be the best solution. I was thinking of doing that, but I was confused as to why the original developer would program it this way. I'll wait for some other answers but if changing the response is the best way to go i'll accept your answer.

Comment: Maybe because they are other applications using the API ? If the API can receive and response in JSON it will be easier to use it with AngularJS. A lot of old service still use SOAP with XML and the main reason is because they interoperate with other service. http://blog.feedly.com/2009/03/03/jsonrest-vs-xmlsoap/ and https://blog.westmonroepartners.com/mobile-web-services-jsonrest-vs-xmlsoap/