# Get XML document from angular $resource

Tags: xml, angularjs, spring

I deal with XML document on angular. I get from the spring server XML string, with type `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE`. first, I create a $http call, and parse the response to XML document with $.parseXML(response) on the transformResponse, like:

```
    $http({
                    method  : 'GET',
                    url     : "/XML",
                    timeout : 10000,
                    params  : {
                        graphFileName: scope.graphFileName
                    }, 
                    transformResponse : function(data) {
                        return $.parseXML(data);
                    }
                }).success(function(data) {
});
```

after, I move the call to factory - and use with $resource. how can I parse the response to document, if the response is:

```
f {0: "<", 1: "?", 2: "x", 3: "m", 4: "l", 5: " ", 6: "v", 7: "e", 8: "r", 9: "s", 10: "i", 11: "o", 12: "n", 13: "=", 14: """, 15: "1", 16: ".", 17: "0", 18: """, 19: " ", 20: "e", 21: "n", 22: "c", 23: "o", 24: "d", 25: "i", 26: "n", 27: "g", 28: "=", 29: """, 30: "U", 31: "T", 32: "F", 33: "-", 34: "8", 35: """, 36: "?", 37: ">", 38: "<", 39: "g", 40: "r", 41: "a", 42: "p", 43: "h", 44: "m", 45: "l", 46: " ", 47: " ", 48: "x", 49: "m", 50: "l", 51: "n", 52: "s", 53: ":", 54: "y", 55: "=", 56: """, 57: "h", 58: "t", 59: "t", 60: "p", 61: ":", 62: "/", 63: "/", 64: "w", 65: "w", 66: "w", 67: ".", 68: "y", 69: "w", 70: "o", 71: "r", 72: "k", 73: "s", 74: ".", 75: "c", 76: "o", 77: "m", 78: "/", 79: "x", 80: "m", 81: "l", 82: "/", 83: "g", 84: "r", 85: "a", 86: "p", 87: "h", 88: "m", 89: "l", 90: """, 91: " ", 92: "x", 93: "m", 94: "l", 95: "n", 96: "s", 97: ":", 98: "y", 99: "e"…}
```

(all the string like array...)

I tried this:

```
getXMLFile: function (graphFileName, callback) {
        $resource("/XML", {graphFileName: graphFileName}, {get: {method: 'GET'}}).get().$promise.then(
           function (rs) {
               callback(rs);
           },
           function (er) {
               callback(undefined);
           }
       );
    }
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular - REST Service XML Links with $Resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799344/angular-rest-service-xml-links-with-resource)

Comment: I don't want to use more lib, like https://code.google.com/p/x2js/. cause when I did that with $http, I don't need anything more.

Comment: Hey, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Transform Response method used to parse the original response sent from Server. In the below snippet, I return the data without converting it to JSON response.

```
 getPrintXML: $resource(`${printUrl}`,null,{
      save:{
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        method: 'POST',
        transformResponse: (data, headers) => ({
                  data: data,
                  headers
        })
      }
    })
```